# Views random list with different css for result 1

Tags: views, theming

I want to create a random list of pictures with views 3 in Drupal 7 where the first picture is larger than the other ones.

So each time I reload I have a random list and the first result is always bigger.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get random results in Views by using the random sort filter.
Then there's quite a few ways to target CSS on the first result.  If your using a list style, the first list item will have a **views-row-first** class.

However, if you want the image to be larger you really want to use a different image style.  This means the field will be different from the rest, and the best way to do that would be to move it to an attachment display.  In there, override the fields and edit the image style.  Override the pager and limit it to 1.

The next problem would be how to exclude the random image from the attachment in the main view (so that you don't get duplicate results).

You can get a view to exclude a result by adding it is an contextual filter. And in the 'more' options, select 'exclude'.

However, I don't know of a way to pass the result from the attachment into the other display as an argument.  They will both inherit the same arguments.

You could generate a random id somehow, and pass this in to your view.

But the tricky bit is how you would generate this random id, it could even be done with another view!  And then also how do you pass this into the view.
I can't quite think of an elegant solution. If you're in a hurry, here's some quick and dirty php code you could put into a custom modules hook_menu callback.

```
$random_id = views_embed_view('your_view_name', 'display_that_outputs_random_id');
print views_embed_view('your_view_name', 'main_display_name', $random_id);
```

There's definitley a better way, if I can think of something I'll let you know.

Thanks
Leon

Answer (score 1):

**Random sort**

There's a specific random sorter called "Global: Random", which you can add like any other sorter in Views, to get the random sorting.

**Image size**

First of all, since you don't mention imagecache, I want to mention that for controlling sizes in general, need to set up two image styles with the imagecache module. Covering that however is out of scope for this question.

There is actually module, which is capable of much more, but has you exact use-case in it's own description. [Dynamic formatters](http://drupal.org/project/dynamic_formatters)' description says 'A simple use case of this is a field in a view that uses a "large" image preset for the first result row and a "small" preset for the rest of the rows.'
While the use-case matches really well, it's also important to note that this requires some amount of coding skills.

Another option is to override the image-fields template. A full book on the theme layer in Drupal could be written, so I can't explain this in full detail here, but I will provide the outline, and you can google and/or open new questions for difficult details.

1. Set up your View to display all your images in the smaller format.
2. In Views, under "Advanced", find the "Theme: Information". Look for the most specific template that matches your requirement, likely something like
   views-view-field--**[name_of_image_field_here]**.tpl.php
3. In views/theme, find views-view-field.tpl.php, copy it to your themes templates directory, and rename it to the field-specific name from the previous step.
4. In this template file, you can now override the imagecache preset for the very first image, to be the bigger style you desire instead.
   To have this work only on the very first image, you will need a static variable

Code example:

```
static $firstImage = true;
if ($firstImage) //Use large image cache
$firstImage = false;
```

I realize that if you are new to either coding, or drupal, this can seem very complicated, but as I said, one would need a book to cover all of this in detail.